# Gilbert Strang's video lecture about chaos and Newton's method

Tags: reference-request, chaos-theory

I had seen a video lecture of Gilbert Strang online, which was about chaos and Newton's method.  I could not find it again online, could someone help me locate it?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you've looked, but [Academic Earth](http://academicearth.org/) contains a lot of his lectures. In particular, there are 5 of Strang's lecture series [here](http://academicearth.org/speakers/gilbert-strang-1).